# "location is not accessible" "access is denied" on CD-ROM, no GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I am a domain admin for my work network, and I have a client (mine), that is not able to access it's CD-ROM (note that USB storage is accessible).

I have attempted the following:

1) Verified with RSoP that there are no group policies are propagating that include disabling read/execute or write for CD-ROMs (or any devices).

2) Verified that the devices are allowed in the BIOS.

3) Uninstall "anti-virus" agent (in the hopes that there might be some device control policy propagating that I'm unaware of).

None of these items helped.

Is anyone familiar with policies of settings that I might have missed to re-enable CD/DVD-ROM access?

Comment: Can you log into another computer with your account and use their CD-ROM? If so, it's not a user-level policy setting.  Are you sure the CD-ROM isn't just broken?  IE: Can you boot from it? Can you see and use it when you boot to a 3rd party OS?  Have you tried more than 1 disk?

Comment: I've tested as another user locally with the same problem.  I will have to swap in a known good drive to really test it, but I can't imagine it's a hardware based issue.  Very weird.

Comment: "I can't imagine it's a hardware based issue" Why not? Optical drives break, and they break often (in comparison to most other PC components). :)

Comment: Instead of "I can't imagine," I should have said "it would be surprising," as an "access denied" error message usually indicates an error is being thrown above hardware.

Comment: Optical drives are weird in general, and getting an "Access denied" for a failing optical drive is not unusual.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple users on the same computer have the same problem with it regardless of the disk used, and you can't boot form the drive using a bootable CD, then your optical drive is most likely broken.

Getting an "Access denied" for a failing optical drive is not unusual.

Try a replacement drive.